# Ошибка при запуске проекта QT

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

Вот такую ​​ошибку получаю:
The code execution cannot proceed because Qt6Core.dll was not found . Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

Есть подозрения что это из-за visual C++

Comment: Точно из за visual c++ :) у вас отсутствует кусок QT а именно ```Qt6Core.dll``` вам по англицки на белом написано "**Переустановка программы может исправить проблему**", но нет, виноват точно visual c++

Comment: Спасибо, я переустанавливал сам QT, но результат не очень. Переустановка visual C++ поможет?

Comment: Переставлять следует свою программу. И при этом убедиться, что вместе с ней вы ставите и все dll зависимости, в т.ч. Qt6Core.dll

Comment: Спасибо всем, проблему решил!!!